# Jquery validation Not working after checking and unchecking (Checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, triggers

I have an appointments plugin with an option to select particular days in a checkbox manner. I have added a custom validation for the field. Everything works fine. When we check the checkbox and uncheck it the validation doesn't work.
Here is my code,

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     jQuery(document).on('click','.ladda-button',function(){
          oniter();
    });

 });
function oniter(){

    if (jQuery(".valid").find(".active").length>=1) {
        // alert(123);
    }
    else {
      jQuery('.removeval').remove();
        jQuery(".validation_text").append("<font class='removeval'>Please Select a Day</font>");
    }
    jQuery(".valid").on ('change',function(){
      jQuery(".validation_text").remove();
    });
  }
```

I tried giving it in the same page and also calling the function on onclick of the button. here is the html of button.

```
<button class="bookly-next-step bookly-js-next-step bookly-btn ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in" data-spinner-size="40" onclick="oniter();">
```

what is that am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some checking, i have found that ma validation was actually working and it was the validation text which was not getting appended. So instead of appending the text i used hide and show functions and it now works perfectly.
function oniter(){

```
    if (jQuery(".valid").find(".active").length>=1) {
        // alert(123);
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.removeval').show();

    }
    jQuery(".valid").on ('change',function(){
      jQuery(".removeval").hide();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For checkboxed i use from following approach:

```
 $('.valid input').click(function(){this.checked ? $(".validation_text").show() : $(".validation_text").hide()});
```

Comment: in the $('.valid')  .valid is selector of your checkbox?

Comment: valid is the class of my checkbox div

Comment: So use this one $('.valid input') or define special class or id for your checkbox and access with that

Comment: still no luck !!

Comment: at this time i am using this approach in my app